# How can I determine whether a vector contains another vector respecting order in R?

Tags: r

If I have vectors like these:

```
vec1 <- c("a", "b", "c")
vec2 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
```

I can use

```
vec1 %in% vec2
TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

to determine whether vec1 is contained within vec2. However, I need to respect the relative order, and this approach does not:

```
vec3 <- c("e", "d", "c", "b", "a") 
vec 1 %in% vec3 #should return false because not in abc order
TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

How can I determine if one vector is contained within another with the same relative order in both vectors? Thanks!

Edit: The vectors are character vectors, but may contain other elements between the ones I care about. For example, I want the following to return TRUE:

```
vec1 <- c("a", "b", "c")
vec4 <- c("a", "x", "b", "c", "y")
```

Comment: Are your actual vectors character vectors? If so, it may be simplest to `paste` them together and then use `grep` or `grepl`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can collapse your vector into a regex pattern and use `grepl`

```
vec1 <- c("a", "b", "c")
vec2 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
grepl(paste(vec1, collapse=".*"), paste(vec2, collapse=""))
# TRUE
vec3 <- c("e", "d", "c", "b", "a")
grepl(paste(vec1, collapse=".*"), paste(vec3, collapse=""))
# FALSE
vec4 <- c("a", "x", "b", "c", "y")
grepl(paste(vec1, collapse=".*"), paste(vec4, collapse=""))
# TRUE
```

EDIT: Based on G5W's comment, you can add a delimiter in case each element is not a character but might be a short string. The delimiter will break up the entries of your vector

```
vec5 <- c("a", "b", "c")
vec6 <- c("ab", "c")
vec7 <- c("ab", "e", "c", "d")
grepl(paste(vec5, collapse="-.*"), paste(vec7, collapse="-"))
# FALSE
grepl(paste(vec6, collapse="-.*"), paste(vec7, collapse="-"))
# TRUE
```

Comment: This works if the strings are all letters,  but may not work if the strings might be "a" or "b" or "ab"

Comment: What if they weren't strings at all but arbitrary objects?

Comment: @JackBrookes a little beyond the scope of the post? I'm certainly not advocating my answer as a catch-all for every data object

Comment: Maybe, but the title doesn't indicate strings, so the solution may not satisfy searchers arriving here

Comment: @JackBrookes hopefully this comment section will suffice for a warning

Answer (score 1):

The `match` function returns the ordering of one vector inside another. Then the sequential differences of that result will be strictly positive if and only if the "relative order" you seek is present.

```
all(vec1 %in% vec4) & all(diff(match(vec1, vec4)) >0 )
[1] TRUE
# also passes the additonal tests
 all(vec5 %in% vec7) & all(diff(match(vec5, vec7)) >0 )
#[1] FALSE
 all(vec6 %in% vec7) & all(diff(match(vec6, vec7)) >0 )
#[1] TRUE
```